# How to pull image from asset pipeline with JQuery Append

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm unable to get the image from the images folder when I use append. I tried to use two different methods so far. `<%= asset_path 'image' %>` and `<%= image_tag %>` Neither are inserting the image. I am getting the tag itself back. How can I append an image from the image folder with jQuery? My code is below.

image_insertion.coffee

```
inbox_avatar = $("[data-behavior='messages'][data-inbox-id='#{data.inbox_id}']")
inbox_avatar.append("<%= asset_path 'chat-icon.png' %>")
```

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with Ruby, but from what I can see `asset_path` returns the URL of the image as a string. jQuery's `append()` method accepts HTML. In which case, what you need to do is concatenate the URL in to a valid `<img src="..." />` element. You could also just use a relative path from the root of your site and negate the need for any server side code at all.

Comment: I changed the image_tag to the normal format <img src='chat-icon.png' /> But, it won't populate the view. Rails is only locating the image file after I refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a straight-up `coffee` file. In which case, you don't have access to `erb` like:

```
"<%= asset_path 'chat-icon.png' %>"
```

Remember, your js is running client-side *after* your `html.erb` has been rendered server-side.

If you want to get a new `img` html blob, you'll have to do an `ajax` call back to the server.

Alternatively, if you're *always* appending the *same* `img` in the same location, then I think the easiest thing to do would be:

1. Render the `chat-icon.png` server-side inside of an image wrapper
2. Use CSS to have the wrapper `display: none`
3. Use js to do a `$('#wrapper-id').show()` or similar

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the `erb` engine on your file if you want it to work that way. Rename your file `image_insertion.coffee.erb` and it should work fine.

You might also have to something like this to actually load the image once it has been appended to your div (100 is just a placeholder height and width):

```
$('<img src="'+ <%= asset_path 'chat-icon.png' %> +'">').load(function() {
  $(this).width(100).height(100).appendTo(image_avatar);
});
```

In a pinch you could hardcode the path. It's most likely in `/assets/images/`. If not, just make sure you start the path at `/assets`

```
$('<img src="/assets/images/chat-icon.png">').load(function() {
  $(this).width(100).height(100).appendTo('#some_target');
});
```